# XML Comments stored inside external file is not showed by Intellisense

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2017, xml-comments

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc) MSDN guide for commenting my code.

I discovered i can use [external files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc#include) to achieve the same result in a more clean way.

However, my IntelliSense don't show those comments on Visual Studio (in this case the file is stored in the root of the application, same level of the `.sln` file).
[screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIlvo.jpg)

I followed this steps to assure it's not a faulty project:

1. I created a new .NET Class Library
2. I created a new file on the project called docs.xml (like the guide)
3. I've put this code inside this new file:

   `<docs>
       <members name="class1">
          <Class1>
              <summary> This is a test description </summary>
          </Class1>
       </members>
   </docs>`
4. I've enabled the "XML documentation file" inside the project settings and left the default value (`bin\ClassLibrary1.xml`)
5. I inserted the xml  above my class declaration: 
   `/// <include file='docs.xml' path='docs/members[@name="class1"]/Class1/*'
   public class Class1 { }`
6. Built the solution
7. However there is no summary specified.

In the compiled bin xml file the summary specified in this file is present and using tools like `SandCastle` shows the documentation correctly.

Am I doing something wrong or this is the default behaviour?
I searched around the net (especially here) and haven't found a proper solution at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/12389910-include-external-xml-documentation-in-intellisense

Given the official answer to user suggestion, it sounds like Visual Studio simply doesn't have such feature as of Visual Studio 2017.